# How do I send an email alert through python if a particular string is missing in my file?

Tags: python, pandas, smtp

im new to python and smptplib
I am trying to send an email alert if "#--- END -----------------------------------" is not detected in my file. I am so far able to send an email if there is a non numerical in the file but not sure how to create a function that lets u send an email if a string does not exist or is missing

```
import pandas as pd
    import smtplib
    from email.message import EmailMessage
    
df = pd.read_fwf(r'factadwords.Rout', header=None)

    df
    Out[31]: 
                                                          0
    0     R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15) -- "Lost Library ...
    1     Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statis...
    2             Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    3     R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY N...
    4     You are welcome to redistribute it under certa...
                                                    ...
    1337  > #--- END -----------------------------------...
    1338                                                  >
    1339                                      > proc.time()
    1340                               user  system elapsed
    1341                              73.89    7.00 1208.56
    
    [1342 rows x 1 columns]

def email_alert(subject,body,to):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(body)
    msg['subject'] = subject
    msg['to'] = to
        
    user = "xx@gmail.com"
    msg['from'] = user
    password = "clqdgqyfrlccisynd"
        
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(user,password)
    server.send_message(msg)
        
    server.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for col in cols_to_check:
        if not df[col].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float))).all():
            body = "There is no END in the file" + col + "."
            print(body)
            email_alert("Hey",body,"xx.t@cinset.com")
```

what should I change or add in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```py
df[0].str.contains(end_str).any()
```

It will check if any of the rows in column 0 contains your END string. If at least one of them contains the required string it will return True. If no rows contain the string it will return False.

You could do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

end_str = '#--- END -----------------------------------'

df = pd.read_fwf(r'factadwords.Rout', header=None)

if not df[0].str.contains(end_str).any():
    print("There is no END in the file")
    email_alert("Hey",body,"xx.t@cinset.com")
```

pandas.Series.str.contains: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html
pandas.DataFrame.any: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html